# Clustering with weka

Tags: cluster-analysis, weka, carrot2

I have saved a google query (title and description) of 100 results. It has this format:

```
Title                Description
Spain - Wikipedia    Spain is a democracy organised in the form of a parliamentary government under a constitutional monarchy. It is a developed country with the world's fourteenth
```

You get an idea. I successfully load this CSV file into weka. Apply NominalToString filter first (because it loads in Nominal). And then apply the StringToWordVector with the following options:

```
IDFTransform - True
TFTTransform - T
normalaize - T
outputWordCounts - T
tokenizer - Alphabetical
WordstoKeep - 100
```

More or less. I then get a list of words, sometimes I use the NGramTokenizer to have at least 3 words.

After that I go to Cluster and choose K-means. This doesn't works very well as it puts 90% in one cluster . Or maybe it is right....

What does happen when I choose Use training set here as I don't have anything yet? What option should I use? I want to form clusters like in categories(Tourism, Sports, Economy,...). Can Weka do that like Carrot2 does? Or at least form clusters.

Thanks.

Comment: Increase WordstoKeep to may be 1000 and check the results

Comment: Yeah I did that, a little better but still like 84% are in the same cluster. Maybe my sample is too little? That assuming what I'm doing is correct....

Comment: What have you set for `number of clusters`? Increase that to 10 and check

Comment: Clustered Instances

 0       1 (  1%)
 1       1 (  1%)
 2      89 ( 91%)
.....

This is with 10 clusters and 1000 WordsToKeep.

Comment: Did you use stemmer and stopwordsHandler options in StringToWordVector?

Comment: Yeah, the result is the same. Maybe I should use other data.